# Background image on Windows 8 App Splash screen

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, splash-screen

Is there a way to replace the background color of a Windows store application splash screen with a background image ? (I am not speaking of the extended splash screen but about the fixed/first one)

The manifest file only allows to place a Logo image and a background color, but have anyone managed to bypass this limitation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible right now. Extended splash is your only option.